# how can I run process in background with java dynamic web project

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp, servlets

When the user clicks the button on the web page, an action is taking place (api request for 1000 records).
I m parsing a csv file and then send request to google api. There are 1000 records in csv file.

This process can take 15-20 minutes. I do not want timeout of web page.

How do I get this to work in the background? or increase the page timeout property to 15-20min.

Im using Java Dynamic web project. (Java 8, Tomcat 8.5)

Thanks.

Comment: 15 - 20 minutes for a http request-response is really bad sign, you need to find out where the bottle necking is happening in you back-end(typically it should be in order of milli seconds). Try to find out if its network issue, slow hardware or really code/design issue. If actually your process needs that much time, for such use cases rather use async calls.

Comment: Im sorry I forgot to write. Because lots of records are processing. Api request and response time is normal for one record. What is the maximum timeout duration of web page?

Comment: Ok if that is normal time then I suppose you have to either use a Async call from front end, or A sync call which executes your processing logic in different thread at server side and returns the response(with just acknowledgment of job submission) from main thread. you can use some queuing/messaging system for such jobs(at back end). The end user will not get the results immediately but can be notified during logged in session or could see results on next log in.(will need some front end changes as well.. i.e how you will show users the notification for completed jobs)

Comment: Thank you very much @Shail016 . Im a beginner. How can I search sample application for this. Or could you share the example code for Async  calling from front end.

Comment: if you are a newbie to web development, then you need to learn java script or some js framework like jquery, dojo etc, for handling async http request/response from frontend. Or as i told in second part of my comment above, you can just call sync http  request( like you are already calling on button click) and execute your processing logic in separate java thread. then,  once the job is complete you need to notify your UI with the results (which again will require some javascript/jquery magic at frontend).

Comment: Please try to dig in these topics                                                                             
1. Client side : AJAX,jason, javascript,Jquery (or any other client side scripting API of your choice ) etc .                                                                                         2.  For server side java multi threading, Java messaging Servcie (JMS) queues topics etc.